# Yocto build error during merge of own custom linux kernel v4.19

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, renesas-rx

I am inserting my linux kernel in yocto build for Renesas RZN1D. But at 98% build process is getting failed and asking for missing configuration for rzn1. How to resolve this error?

Log data as follows-

***ERROR: linux-rzn1-4.19-r4 do_configure: No default configuration for rzn1d400-db / rzn1_defconfig available.
ERROR: linux-rzn1-4.19-r4 do_configure: Function failed: do_configure

Log data follows:

| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure

| install: cannot stat '/home/synergy/GitRepos/Synergy/poky/build/tmp/work/rzn1d400_db-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-rzn1/4.19-r4/git/arch/arm/configs/rzn1_defconfig': No such file or directory

| ERROR: No default configuration for rzn1d400-db / rzn1_defconfig available.

| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.

I changed meta-rzn1/recipe-kernel/linux/linux-rzn1_v4.19.bb file to get my own kernel files to be included during build process but it is getting failed.

Comment: Have you checked if the required files are available before the do_configure step? How did you try to make them available? How does your recipe look like?

Comment: 1. rzn1_defconfig file is available at its location but do_configure says its is not available. My recipe of look like this as I am giving SRC_URI path in this file of /meta-rzn1/recipe-kernel/linux/linux-rzn1_4.19.bb as follows -
# Renesas RZ/N1 repo, use latest release
SRCBRANCH = "prp-support"
SRC_URI = "file:///home/synergy/GitRepos/Synergy/rzn1_linux;protocol=file;branch=${SRCBRANCH}" . Do I have to edit this SRC_URI in other receipe_kernel?

Comment: `rzn1_defconfig file is available at its location` - at what location? at `/home/synergy/GitRepos/Synergy/poky/build/tmp/work/rzn1d400_db-poky-linux-gnueabi/linux-rzn1/4.19-r4/git/arch/arm/configs/rzn1_defconfig`? Also, is this file part of the kernel source, or do you add it to it as an extra file/patch?

Comment: NO.....rzn1_defconfig is available at home\synergy\GitRepos\Synergy\rzn1_linux\arch\arm\configs\rzn1_defconfig and This rzn1_linux is my custom kernel source which I want to include during yocto build process. But it gives error that it is not available at its location. My question is if I want to include my kernel source to the build process, I need to edit SRC_URI in /meta-rzn1/recipe-kernel/linux/linux-rzn1_v4.19.bb or something else.